# altair transform_aggregate is not producing the same results as encoding method

Tags: altair

I am looking at how transform_aggregate works compared to the encoding aggregate method and they seem to be producing different results. I am not sure I am using transform_aggregate correctly here.

Here is the example I tried

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

T = ["Hot", "Cold"]
P = ["high","medium","low"]
A = ["0-50","50+"]

c = [[t, p, a] for t in T for p in P for a in A]
df = pd.DataFrame(c, columns=["Temperature", "Precipitation", "AgeGroup"])
df["Value"] = [int(x) for x in np.random.sample(df.shape[0]) * 10]
df
```

Produces:

| Temperature | Precipitation | AgeGroup | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hot | high | 0-50 | 0 |
| Hot | high | 50+ | 3 |
| Hot | medium | 0-50 | 4 |
| Hot | medium | 50+ | 7 |
| Hot | low | 0-50 | 9 |
| Hot | low | 50+ | 0 |
| Cold | high | 0-50 | 9 |
| Cold | high | 50+ | 1 |
| Cold | medium | 0-50 | 2 |
| Cold | medium | 50+ | 6 |
| Cold | low | 0-50 | 4 |
| Cold | low | 50+ | 1 |

A couple of aggregates in python that I want to reproduce in Altair

```
df.groupby(["Temperature","Precipitation"]).agg(
    {"Value":"sum"}
)
```

| Temperature | Precipitation | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cold | high | 10 |
| Cold | low | 5 |
| Cold | medium | 8 |
| Hot | high | 3 |
| Hot | low | 9 |
| Hot | medium | 11 |

and

```
df.groupby(["Precipitation"]).agg(
    {"Value":"sum"}
)
```

| Precipitation | Value |
| --- | --- |
| high | 13 |
| low | 14 |
| medium | 19 |

In altair I can do this:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    y="Temperature:N",
    x="Precipitation:N",
    color=alt.Color("sum(Value):Q"),
    tooltip=[alt.Tooltip("sum(Value):Q")]
)
```

And get

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5X3p.png)

and

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    y="sum(Value):Q",
    x="Precipitation:N",
)
```

returns

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHdfq.png)

However the following does not work

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    x="Temperature:N",
    y="Precipitation:N",
    color="total_value:Q"
).transform_aggregate(
    total_val="sum(Value)",
    groupby=["Temperature","Precipitation"])
```

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w05NI.png)

and

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x="Precipitation",
    y="total_value:Q"
).transform_aggregate(
    total_val='sum(Value)',
    groupby=["Precipitation"])
```

[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYQNk.png)

It seems using `transform_aggregate` is producing Null outcomes for `total_value`.

I am using:

- python 3.11.4
- altair 5.1.1

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you call the variable `total_val` in `transform_aggregate`, but `total_value` in the chart encoding. Change it to be the same and you will see the expected result.

Bonus: [Altair charts now also have a `transformed_data()` method](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/index.html#accessing-transformed-data) that will return a pandas dataframe with the transforms applied (requires vegafusion installed).